# Databricks CDC (Change Data Capture) implementation

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

I am new to databricks and wants to implement incremental loading in databricks reading and writing data from Azure blob storage. I came across CDC method in Databricks. I am saving the data in delta format and also creating tables while writing the data?

Can someone please provide me with scripts/code to read only rows in a table that are updated/inserted/deleted since the last time notebook ran. So that I don't have to process all rows again and again.

Please help me if I understood anything wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: see here: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-streaming.html